# Using async-await with node-fetch does not return the response to the calling method

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, node-fetch

I have a function defined in a module that is supposed to do a fetch and return the response. I am having trouble returning the response from the fetch. The calling function gets the return value as "undefined".

*I am new to JavaScript and Node so might need a little bit of hand-holding if you don't mind.*

**Calling function**

```
async function executeTest() {
    try {
        const response = await bpc.postLendingApplication(
            blendConnection,
            loanData
        );
        console.log("Response from POST Loan: ", response);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

**Module function doing the fetch request**

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
async function postLendingApplication(connection, data) {
    console.log("Processing POST Loan.");
    await fetch(connection.url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: connection.headers,
        body: data,
    }).then(async res => {
        console.log("Status: ", res.status);
        console.log("StatusText: ", res.statusText);
        console.log("OK: ", res.ok);
        return await res;
    });
}
```

**The console output is:**

```
Processing POST Loan.
Status:  200
StatusText:  OK
OK:  true
Response from POST Loan:  undefined
```

As you can see, the fetch did what it was supposed to do and if I log the res.json() within the module method, it prints the payload. But I would like to return the error and response from the fetch so the module behaves as a generic method and the processing and error handling is done in the calling method.

Comment: You don't need `async/await` inside `then`.

Comment: In your case you either should return `Promise` or rewrite your function in other way.

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov Nope. `async function` automatically returns a promise. Your return value is the resolution of it.

Comment: @Chance you didn't get what I mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you mark a `function` as `async`, JavaScript will always return a `Promise`, thus making it asynchronous. When you return a value, it is resolving the `Promise`. Using `await` inside of these functions "pauses"  execution (it is technically creating a new function for code that occurs after the `await`) until the awaited `Promise` is resolved, standing in place of the usage of `then(callback)`. As such, you don't need `then` inside of any `async function`.

You do, however, need to treat your own `async function` as a `Promise`.

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
async function postLendingApplication(connection, data) {
    try {
      console.log("Processing POST Loan.");

      // the await eliminates the need for .then
      const res = await fetch(connection.url, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: connection.headers,
          body: data,
      })
      // this code is resumed once the fetch Promise is resolved.
      // res now has a value.
      console.log("Status: ", res.status);
      console.log("StatusText: ", res.statusText);
      return res;
   }
   catch(err) { 
     // because the promise could error, it is advised to use
     // try/catch. With a Promise, you would .then(cb).catch(errHandler)
     // but async/await doesn't utilize callbacks.

     // perform error handling or you can bubble it up.
    throw err
}
```

When calling `postLendingApplication(connection, data)` make sure that you are either using `await`, if inside an `async function` or `postLendingApplication(connection, data).then(callback)` as the return value will be a `Promise`.

```
postLendingApplication(connection, data).then(callback).catch(errHandler)
```

Comment: The solution worked, thanks! Another follow up question thought, let's say I removed one of the important elements from the connection which results in a runtime error. If I enclose all the code you shared within a try-catch, the problem now is that the calling function fails because it didn't get a response object back but an exception. Is there a best-practice that I can follow here?  catch (error) {
  console.log("Catch error");
  return error;
 }

Comment: You don't want to return the error. You want to throw it unless you prepare for it.

For example, you could have a return of something like `{ status: 'failure', error: err }

Comment: @VarunVerma oh no problem whatsoever. `async`/`await` are very commonly misunderstood. The `async function` is a bit of magic.

Answer (score 2):

You forget to return form function. `return await fetch(connection.url, {`
You dont need `async-await` in `then` function. You can return `res.json()`

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
async function postLendingApplication(connection, data) {
    console.log("Processing POST Loan.");
    return await fetch(connection.url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: connection.headers,
        body: data,
    }).then(res => {
        console.log("Status: ", res.status);
        console.log("StatusText: ", res.statusText);
        console.log("OK: ", res.ok);
        return res.json();
    });
}
```